# Run an application while the PC is locked?

Tags: windows

I have an application (winpenguin; it creates cute little penguins that wander around your Windows desktop) that I would like to run when my PC is locked.

How's this possible?

Comment: Need a little bit more detail on what you're trying to do. Which application? What functionality do you need? etc.

Comment: application named winpenguine that i want to run..

Comment: @vishalsharma Can you help me to understand the question. Do you want to run the program only when the PC is locked, or only at certain times regardless of it being locked?

Comment: its only going to run when pc is getting locked??

Comment: @vishalsharma Hang on, you want to run a program which is a visual thing, only when the PC is locked, and therefore not visible to you?

Comment: what i want is when i press win+L on my windows after lock screen an application which is visual thing gets run..

Comment: Do you mean that you want to run a screensaver-like program visible on your lock screen, when your PC is locked?

Comment: yes that is i want

Comment: is there something customized on autohotkey????

Comment: @vishalsharma: Can you then clarify your question?

Comment: @vishalsharma - Why do you want a visual program to run when you can't see it?

Comment: its something like alerter for others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless the program is designed to be a screen saver you can't run it when the computer is locked. By this I mean when the computer becomes idle and the rules for a screen saver apply.

Obviously if the program is already running it will continue to run. If you want to see it still running then you need to disable the screen saver.

If it is a screen saver go to:

> **Control Panel > Personalization > Change Screen Saver**

then select the screen saver from the list:

[image]

Comment: +1 for `Unless the program is designed to be a screen saver you can't run it when the computer is locked`.

Comment: Is this right? I have programs which run and continue to do so when PC is locked (like Visual Studio); Are we mixing terms, between logging off and locking or is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: @DaveRook - Running programs will continue. I meant programs to run **when** the screen is locked.

Comment: @ChrisF - I'm sorry, I still don't understand. If this is the case, then why does Scheduled Tasks give me the option to do this whether I'm logged in or not. I just wrote a bat file to copy a file, scheduled it for 4 minutes time, locked my PC, waited 10 minutes, returned and the program had run.

Comment: @DaveRook - Scheduled Tasks is usually for programs that don't have a GUI or require user input.

Comment: @ChrisF ...ah!! The penny now drops! Yes, of course. Thank you for taking the time to explain this.

Comment: can it be done through autohotkey??

Comment: @vishalsharma You are missing the point, if the program is not a screen saver it will run, **but you will not be able to see it running**, so what is the point?

Comment: (necrothread, but ah well). The biggest point I can see is: transfering a lot of files and going away from the computer while the copying is in process. Especially in a workplace setting, it is common that you must lock the computer if you are not near it.

Answer (score 13):

You may create a scheduled task using the following steps (the task will run when the PC gets locked):

1. Open `Task Scheduler`
2. Click on `Create task...` under `Action` (menu bar)
3. Name the task on the `General` tab
4. Add a new trigger on the tab `Triggers`

   - Begin the task: `On workstation lock` (drop-down menu on top of the `New Trigger` window)
5. Finally, add a new action on the `Actions` tab (you just have to browse for the program)

Comment: This is the exact solution for "running an application while the PC is locked?" (at least win7 users)